# Trouble updating my site to Drupal 7.34. Maybe problems connecting programs to webserver

Tags: drupal-7, extract, tar, drush

I am new to this, and I hope someone can help me with the supposedly simple task of downloading an update of Drupal. A few months ago I finally created a website at Unoeuro and with Drupal. I even got around to chose themes and put content in.

**My system**: Windows 7, Webserver Apache, host: Unoeuro, run Drupal 7.32 just fine, besides the warning message on most of the pages on my site's Admin.

**Problem**: A little while ago Drupal started saying "*There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates."*

When I follow the link, it says: *"Manual updates required"* and *"Updates of Drupal core are not supported at this time."* 
Do you think THAT is the reason, why I can't make it work? 
However, since there is a link to the latest update, Drupal 7.34. and it is coloured red and looks like I need it.

When I follow the Update link, I'm told to download it through one of three methods- https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal After checking my Systemrequirements through NetCraft.com, reading the Installation Guide, and downloading and extracting the 7.34 zip-file with Zipwizzard, my command prompt doesn't know, what I'm talking about.

I've tried alsmost every combination of methods, both the Drush and Command Prompt, and different zip-files and tar-files and extracting in every command prompt. 
**Problem:** It seems like none of them are not connected to a 'prober Drupal environment', as they say.

I've tried changing the PATH to the drupal-7.34 folder, where the environment should be (I suppose, because I just downloaded it). But the command prompt still says '... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file' or that the command is not made in a 'prober Drupal Environment'.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I hope someone can give me a hint about it.

Answer (score 0):

Bro you need to be in the correct folder to use drush to update your site.  If you are running a non-multi site instance move to [drupal_root]/sites/all and run the command "drush up", press y a few times and enjoy.  SO thats:

- ssh selsen@selsonssite.com
- cd [drupal_root]/sites/all
- drush up -y

PS using -y on drush up means you don't have to press y multiple times.

You can also contact me @ josh@hamrent.com for more Drupal support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work. New problem came up. There was problems with ssh and then the [drupal_root]etc. doesn't exist. and 'drush' is not an internal or external command etc. What works the most is what I found at this place: http://drupalistasgroup.com/installing-drush-7-windows-xampp

Comment: Maybe you can help me with the next problem: To find my website's root directory. When I searched for a solution, there was a problem inside of that too. That I can't even access this ftp://[my website address] for some reason. When I google THAT problem, it seems like I could solve it through lowering the firewall. ... But I'm kind of stuck. It's like pandoras box just to get a supposedly 'secure' new update of Drupal. Really weird - Any ideas?

Comment: If you can't SSH out to your server to do things it will be very difficult to do most Drupaly things around your site.  Additionally I would recommend a nice Ubuntu Linux machine for running Drupal if you are new to using the command line to do things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. And if I don't currently have access to a nice Ubuntu Linux machine, do you think there's any solution to my problem, that I can't SSH out to my server? (if that is my problem. There is also the problem of not being able to find my website's root directory... any suggestions to that one)? Thanks again for your comment. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Meh sorry on windows there are many different ways to set up a website.  But on my Win7 machine running XAMPP the root to my webserver is C:\xampp\htdocs\<some drupal install> SO if my drupal install folder is called "drupal-install", in order for drush to work, I need to be under C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-install\sites\all.  Additionally if you run the command "drush" and the response is "not a valid command" or an error of some sort, drush is probably not installed on your server.